# Java hangs when trying to close a ProcessBuilder OutputStream

Tags: java, process

I have the following Java code to start a ProcessBuilder, open an OutputStream, have the process write a string to an OutputStream, and then close the OutputStream.  The whole thing hangs indefinitely when I try to close the OutputStream.  This only happens on Windows, never on Mac or Linux.

Some of the related questions seem to be close to the same problem I'm having, but I haven't been able to figure out how to apply the answers to my problem, as I am a relative newbie with Java.  Here is the code.  You can see I have put in a lot of println statements to try to isolate the problem.

```
    System.out.println("GenMic trying to get the input file now");
    System.out.flush();
    OutputStream out = child.getOutputStream();
    try {
        System.out.println("GenMic getting ready to write the input file to out");
        System.out.flush();
        out.write(intext.getBytes());  // intext is a string previously created
        System.out.println("GenMic finished writing to out");
        System.out.flush();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("GenMic closed OutputStream");
        System.out.flush();
    } catch (IOException iox) {
        System.out.println("GenMic caught IOException 2");
        System.out.flush();
        String detailedMessage = iox.getMessage();
        System.out.println("Exception: " + detailedMessage);
        System.out.flush();
        throw new RuntimeException(iox);
    }
```

And here is the output when this chunk is executed:

GenMic trying to get the input file now

GenMic getting ready to write the input file to out

GenMic finished writing to out

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that the streams returned by `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` are drained on individual threads and these threads are different from the one on which you close the stream returned by `getOutputStream()`.

Basically it is a requirement to have at least 3 threads per sub-process if you want to manipulate and examine its *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr*.  One of the threads, depending on your circumstances, may be your current execution thread ( the one on which you create ProcessBuilder ).

Comment: I am having a problem and I think this is the solution but I have to try it out.  It isn't easy to find information on how to use Processes and streams, from what I've seen so far.  The Java Tutorial on concurrency has a nice line that "multiprocess applications are outside the scope of this document"...

Answer (score 3):

When that happened to me it was because I hadn't read everything from the stream being written to by the process.

The API docs for the java.lang.Process class say:

> The created subprocess does not have its own terminal or console. All its standard io (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations will be redirected to the parent process through three streams (getOutputStream(), getInputStream(), getErrorStream()). The parent process uses these streams to feed input to and get output from the subprocess. Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock.

I would try calling getInputStream() on the Process instance and writing a loop to read one byte at a time until it reaches EOF. And I'd do the same thing with getErrorStream() just in case the process is writing to stderr.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan, for the quick response.  I do read the output from the subprocess using getInputStream() a few lines after the code I showed, but the code hangs before it gets there.  What does "failure to promptly write" mean?  I'm trying to write as soon as I open the OutputStream.  What else can I do?  Thanks again.

Comment: So you never get as far as "GenMic closed OutputStream," right? You must be getting an exception, could you show us that?
otherwise I'd try waiting on closing the output stream until after reading everything from the inputstream, but that's just a guess.

Comment: That's right... it never gets to "GenMic closed OutputStream".  I do know that the file I am creating with the OutputStream.write() command is completely written, because I can open it and look at it even while the process is still hanging.  You can see I have put println to get any exception messages, but none of them get triggered.  I am going to try your advice to wait to close the output stream until reading everything from input stream.

Comment: odd the exception doesn't show up. maybe change what's caught to Throwable. Also System.out.flush() is very odd, I don't think I've ever called that.

Comment: "I do read the output from the subprocess using getInputStream() a few lines after the code I showed, but the code hangs before it gets there"

... so therefore you should be doing that *first*. In other words in a separate thread. Two threads, one for the output and one for the err.

Comment: Okay, I see why it is necessary to have separate threads.  Does anyone have a closely-related example I can study?  I've been through the Java tutorial on concurrency, but when I try to apply them I'm getting a lot of errors.

Comment: If you read the output in the same thread as you feed it input, you easily deadlock. Think about it, you try to write to the process, but it blocks because your thread hasn't yet read its output. And since you block, your single thread cant advance to the point where it reads from the program

Comment: @nos: OK, I see why I didn't have this problem when I did something like this, in my case I wasn't feeding the process any input.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have anything reading from stdout/stderr of the process ?

It's quite likely the process tries to output something, but gets blocked since noone is reading the output. Meaning your  `out.flush()` or `out.close()` blocks as the process can't get around to process the input since its blocked doing output.