# How to execute a file using Java Runtime

Tags: java, ant, runtime.exec

I'm trying to execute a simple batch file from java using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
but facing issues, 
below is my code snippet

```
public class Path {
        public static void main(String args[]){
            String[] command = new String[3];
            command[0]="cmd";
            command[1]="/C";
            command[2]="D:/alt/a.bat";
    Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getErrorStream()));
            String s = null;
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and the batch a.bat has ant -f runme.xml test in it
and runme.xml resides in D:/alt physical location which has a target test, so far so good
but when i try to execute the java code above, below is the ouput

```
D:\RCPStack\Path>ant -f runme.xml test  Buildfile: runme.xml does not
exist! Build failed
```

when i execute manually it works fine,seems to be the problem is with the code
below is manual execution output
[image]

how to tackle this(i don't know if the code is incorrect) and handle as a best practice

Comment: Your current working direct is likely to be important. Try your second example running in the same directory as the first.

Comment: Take care to read the separate streams in separate threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783190/java-hangs-when-trying-to-close-a-processbuilder-outputstream/2783473#2783473

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the method `Runtime.exec(String cmd, String[] envp, File dir)`
to set the working directory to `D:/alt/`.

This is because Ant must be executed in the directory where runme.xml is so Ant can find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ant -f runme.xml test", null, new File("D:/alt"));//works
```

or

```
p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c a.bat", null, new File("D:/alt"));//works
```