# java multithreading using Process.waitFor() and java.lang.InterruptedException

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

This is the pseudocode of what I have been doing:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmdToExecute);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");
    StreamGobbler outStreamGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");

    errorGobbler.start();
    outStreamGobbler.start();
    int exitValue = process.waitFor();
    process.destroy();
```

I am getting InterruptedException while using

> Process.waitFor()

command. It was fine when it was a single threaded java app. But
now its a multithreaded app, I am getting

> java.lang.InterruptedException

on that particulat line.
Java doc says:

> Throws:  InterruptedException - if the current thread is interrupted
>   by another thread while it is waiting, then the wait is ended and an
>   InterruptedException is thrown

I understand what it means because 1 thread might be waiting while another wants to wait too but how do I get over this exception and also I will be able to use waitFor().

Any help is appreaciated. I didn't find necessary to post the code, but let me know if you guys need it.

Code for ExecutorService:

```
while(...){
                          .......
        execServ.execute(...);
    }
    execServ.shutdown();
            while(!execServ.isTerminated()){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
```

Comment: "1 thread might be waiting while another wants to wait too".  No that's not quite it.  It means that some other thread interrupted the `wait()` call.

Comment: Thanks Gray for correcting me, What should I be doing to eliminate this error?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783190

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you understand what the Javadoc means. It is saying that if some other thread calls [`interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) on the thread that is executing the code you posted before or during its call of `waitFor()`, an `InterruptedException` will be thrown. It has nothing to do with two threads waiting for something at the same time.

Does your program explicitly call `interrupt()` anywhere? Alternatively, are you executing this process through an `ExecutorService`? When you cancel a task that has been submitted to an executor, it may be interrupted.

Comment: I have added the code for ExecutorSAervice. Could you put some light on it please?

Comment: @user122591 That looks okay. You are calling `shutdown()`, not `shutdownNow()`, so your running tasks should not be interrupted. Do you call `interrupt()` anywhere? Does another thread have access to your `ExecutorService`?

Comment: I have 6 threads running at the same time. ANd I am not being to able to figure it out why and who is calling interrupt()? Is there a way to find who/why is calling interupt? I am not calling interrupt anywhere.thanks

Comment: One way to call interrupt is to retrieve a Future corresponding to the Runnable task : `Future<?> future = pool.submit(task);` and to cancel this future : `future.cancel();`